# Applying a Single Gradient Fill Color to a multipart feature

Tags: qgis, symbology, color, multipart, fill

So I have an indicatrix covering a world map for the purpose of illustrating distortions for different projections. I want the circles of the indicatrix to share the same gradient fill color, as opposed to each having their own individual gradient fill. To clarify, here is a picture of the indicatrix:

[image]

Notice that each circle has its own individual gradient fill. What I want to do is have QGIS treat them all as part of the same shape, so that a single gradient fill is spread out across them all. To visualize this, take the gradient fill for this circle:

[image]

...and then use the indicatrix to "clip" the circle without actually changing the fill. (I literally tried this already fyi. Just creates an visually identical shapefile to the indicatrix.)

I figured all I had to do was dissolve my indicatrix shapefile to a single feature and it would replicate this result, but apparently the issue is more complex than that. Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1):

With corresponding settings, this can be easily done, see screenshot below. My settings are as follows:

- Gradient type: `Radial`
- Coord mode: `Viewport`
- Spread: `Repeat`
- Reference point 1: `0.5` for x and y
- Reference point 2: `0.5` for x and `0` for y

This is what you get:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps set the `coord mode` option to `Viewport`, see section Coordinate Modes in [this](http://north-road.com/2014/01/05/waiting-for-qgis-2-2-gradient-fills/) website.